# The specified module could not be found - Adobe PDF Reader C#

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, com

I am using AxAcroPDF to show PDFs in a windows form. Its working everywhere except for a user it is throwing following COM error. I checked with the user and he got Adobe Acrobat Professional 8.0 installed.. Can anyone please help me to find the problem/solution for this issue

```
    System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithoutLicense(Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String license, Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit()
   at DocumentProcessing.PDFViewerForm.InitializeComponent() in D:\PDFTest\PDFViewerForm.Designer.cs:line 56
```

Thanks and Regards,
Anz

Comment: did anyone manage to get a solution for this error